# struct pointer and fixed char

Tags: c#, c++, dll, struct, unmarshalling

i have a structure in my C++ like this

```
struct ST_HDTextInfo
{
    char* font_name;                    
    char* text;                          
    unsigned int font_color;             
    unsigned int background_color;      
    int style;                          
    int font_size;                       
    struct ST_HDTextInfo* next;        
};
```

and i redeclare it in my C# code like this

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential,Pack=4)]
    unsafe struct  ST_HDTextInfo
    {
        [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 25)]
        public fixed char font_name[25];
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.I1, SizeConst = 20)]
        public char[] text;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysUInt)]
        public uint font_color;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysUInt)]
        public uint background_color;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysInt)]
        public EN_FontStyle style;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysInt)]
        public int font_size;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysInt)]
        public ST_HDTextInfo* next;
    };
```

the field **next** is a pointer to same structure. when i use **char[] var** for string variable because structure not have fix size VS take an error on **public ST_HDTextInfo* *next***
but when use fixed char var[SIZE_OF_VAR] the problem resolve but occur another mistake. Filling char* variable is a new problem! i use this code for convert counst string to char*

```
IntPtr p = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAuto("Poor Richard");
char* newCharStr = (char*)(p.ToPointer());

text_info.font_name = newCharStr;
```

in this station my string convert to char* but VS take this error "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer  " !!!

Comment: Should be able to use `string` as the type. i.e. `public string font_name;` Not saying that will immediately fix everything, but that's the way to go and let marshalling worry about the chars and pointers and stuff.

Comment: A `char*` string is not a `UnmanagedType.ByValTStr`. Try `UnmanagedType.LPStr` and a normal string instead of a `char[]`.

Comment: what is EN_FontStyle ?

Comment: If i use string Instead of fixed char the structure memory location become variable and pointer not able to determine momery location and allocation. then compiler take this error "Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type " !!!

Comment: EN_FontStyle  is a ENUM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolve this problem. I use this sample code

```
[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, Size=80)]
    internal unsafe struct ST_HDTextInfo
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public fixed char text[25];
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public fixed char font_name[20];
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public uint font_color;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public uint background_color;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public EN_FontStyle style;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public int font_size;
        [FieldOffset(80 - sizeof(long))]
        public ST_HDTextInfo* next;
    };
```